# How can I insert a constant value and a select value from other table?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert a data from the other table and to another. But first I need to include also the latest id inserted from the parent table. Anyone can help me out?

```
<?php 

        $insert1 = "INSERT INTO purhcase_order
        (Supp_ID, Approved_by, Prepared_by, Estemated_cost)
        VALUES ($suppname, '$appname', '$prepname', $total_cost)";
        // $resultToinsert1 = mysqli_query($connector, $insert1);
        // header('location: purchase-order_staff.php');
        if (mysqli_query($connector, $insert1)) {
            $lastInsertedId = mysqli_insert_id($connector);

            $insert2 = "INSERT INTO purchase_order_product
            (Pur_ord_id, Product_ID, Quantity, Estimated_amount)
            SELECT  $lastInsertedId, A.Product_ID, B.Qty_requested as 
            Quantity, (B.Qty_requested * C.Product_price ) as 
            Estimated_amount from 
            ware_house_product A, purchase_request_product B, 
            supplier_product C, purchase_request D, supplier E 
            WHERE A.Product_ID = B.Product_ID and 
            A.Product_ID=C.Product_ID AND C.Supp_ID=E.Supp_ID 
            AND E.Supp_ID='$suppname' AND 
            D.Pur_req_id='$Purchase_request_id'";

            $resultToinsert2 = mysqli_query($connector, $insert2);
            if ($resultToinsert2 == TRUE) {
                header('location: purchase-order_staff.php');

               }else {
                   echo "Data is not inserted";
               }
            }else {
                echo "Data is not inserted";
            }
        }
 }
?>
```

Comment: ...secretly wishing I was looking at prepared statements.  How isn't your code working properly.  Is this a code dump ...please fix this?

Comment: Your code should work. You can also use the MySQL function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` instead of the variable `$lastInsertedId`.

Comment: When a query fails you should print `mysqli_error($connector)` to see the reason, not just `Data is not inserted`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys now my code is actually working. the error is the "insert1 =  INSERT INTO purhcase_order" which is table dosen't exist. the it was a typo error which is the correct spelling is "purchase_order". thanks for the tip especially the mysqli_error function really help a lot. I'm so happy hehe